Problem with customer name display involving average
I'm trying to write an SQL query that displays customers' names who have a total purchase greater than the average purchase of all purchases.
I tried using the code below, but it gives an error.
SELECT C.FirstName
FROM CUSTOMERS as C
JOIN ORDERS AS O ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
GROUP BY O.CustomerID
HAVING O.TotalPaid < Avg(O.TotalPaid);

And here's the error:
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'O.TotalPaid' in 'having clause'

The HAVING clause only works with aggregate functions. You’d need to restructure your query e.g. using a WHERE clause and with a subquery to get the average

please take a look at why should i tag my database system

It seems that you are having three errors:

You should include the O.TotalPaid into a SUM because the HAVING should contain aggregated data.
You should do a subquery for the average value to keep it constant.
It should be > because you are looking for values greater than the average.

Query should be like this:
SELECT C.FirstName
FROM CUSTOMERS as C
JOIN ORDERS AS O ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
GROUP BY O.CustomerID
HAVING SUM(O.TotalPaid) > (SELECT AVG(TotalPaid) FROM ORDERS);

Another possible option should be including into the SELECT the SUM(O.TotalPaid) like this:
SELECT C.FirstName, SUM(O.TotalPaid)
FROM CUSTOMERS as C
JOIN ORDERS AS O ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
GROUP BY O.CustomerID
HAVING SUM(O.TotalPaid) > (SELECT AVG(TotalPaid) FROM ORDERS);


should be > not < as OP is looking for customers with above average

Answer has been edited. Thank you.

It's not clear if you want to compare each customer's total to the average total across all customers. Or do you want to check that all a customer's orders are higher than the average across the whole set.
For the first, you can use window functions
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
      C.FirstName,
      SUM(O.TotalPaid) AS Total,
      AVG(SUM(O.TotalPaid)) OVER () AS AvgTotalForAll
    FROM CUSTOMERS as C
    JOIN ORDERS AS O ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
    GROUP BY C.CustomerID, C.FirstName
) C
WHERE C.Total > C.AvgTotalForAll;

For the second, you shouldn't do AVG(AVG()) OVER () because that would get incorrect results, instead do SUM(SUM()) OVER () / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ().
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
      C.FirstName,
      MIN(O.TotalPaid) AS MinTotal,
      SUM(O.TotalPaid) AS Total,
      SUM(SUM(O.TotalPaid)) OVER () / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS AvgForAll
    FROM CUSTOMERS as C
    JOIN ORDERS AS O ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
    GROUP BY C.CustomerID, C.FirstName
) C
WHERE C.MinTotal > C.AvgForAll;

